# ExternalInterface passing values from swf to an iFrame on the same page

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, iframe, externalinterface, scorm1.2

On a page I have a an iFrame and a swf, I've been trying to use ExternalInterface to pass values from the swf to the iFrame, anyone ever tried this and had any luck? I won't be able to post any code until tomorrow, will update then if needed.

Thanks in adavnce.

Here is a visualization of what I need to accomplish, perhaps if it can't be done the way I said someone will have a suggestion of another way to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: do you have access to change code on the iframe file?

Comment: yes I have access to all the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to target the frame. This should work with one frame on the page or you will have to change the index.

```
duhFrame = window.frames[0]
targetElement = duhFrame.getElementById('someIframeElement');
```

If this doesn't work for you then use LocalConnection and put a hidden swf on the iframe file.
LocalConnection is Global to the browser so be aware that if two browser windows are open you will get two iframes connecting on the same name and will get some funky results.
 So change the connection name via query string and flashvars.
Its a real hackish workaround but it will work.

[EDIT]
One more thing make sure your javascript callback function is getting called as ExternalInterface has major domain issues when running under the file structure and not in a domain(EX: clicking run in the editor ). Try uploading to your server and change your embed code to allow for it. Also dont forget to update your crossdomain.xml(s).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access iframes from outside of them. These are security reasons, and browsers will and should block such attempts.

Comment: unfortunately I need to figure something out, even if it's not the way I described it, added a visualization of what I need to accomplish, any thoughts?